# Can't receive NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification while save context in a NSOperation subclass

Tags: core-data, notifications, nsoperation

I am using [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) to help with core data operation.

I have a `NSOperation` subclass called `OfflineRetrieveOperation`. It retrieve the message from the server and save it.
the code is like this:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [NSManagedObjectContext contextForCurrentThread];
Message *existMessage = [Message MessageWithMessageID:messageID inManagedObjectContext:context];

if (!existMessage) {
  Message *message = [Message insertMessageWithProperties:properties inManagedObjectContext:context];
}
[context save];
```

The notification receiver is initialized like this:

```
- (id)init
{
  self = [super init];

  if (self != nil) {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(contextDidSave:) 
                                                 name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification 
                                               object:[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext]];
    [self setContext:[NSManagedObjectContext context]];
  }
  return self;
}
```

the log:

```
-[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) saveWithErrorHandler:](0x5906a0) Saving Context
-[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) mergeChangesFromNotification:](0x37eab0) Merging changes to *** DEFAULT *** context *** on Main Thread ***
```

Everything seems work fine except I can't receive the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` at all, so that I can't know that I have already finish retrieving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `OfflineRetrieveOperation` is probably creating its own `NSManagedObjectContext`.  When you save that context it will fire the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`.  However you have an observer that will **only** listen for a `NSNotification` being broadcast by the `[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext]`.

Change your observer to consume notifications from your `OfflineRetrieveOperation` internal `NSManagedObjectContext` instead of `[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext]` and it should start receiving them.

Comment: Thank U，Marcus.
I try to do all kind of operation in different thread,then merge the change to [NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext].

Comment: It is the operation's `NSManagedObjectContext` that broadcasts the notification. You need to set the object: of your addNotification to the broadcaster (or nil) to receive the notifications.  I suggest reading how `NSNotification` and `NSNotificationCenter` work.

Comment: Since there is different kind of operations that may change the data,it will be convenience that the notification receiver only care about the defaultContext.
I think I can do this:
        [[OfflineRetrieveOperation context] save];
        [[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext] save];
the second save wile fire a NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification and the notification receiver will receive this.
If the [notification userInfo] have no content,use the NSFetchedResultsController to performFetch and get the latest the data.

Comment: No. Only the operation's context will fire a notification because it is the only one that has a change. Period.  You **MUST** listen for the operation context or nil for this to work.

Comment: I have tried. The second save did fire the NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification,and the [notification userInfo] is empty:
{
    inserted = "{(\n)}";
    updated = "{(\n)}";
}

Comment: The second save is *empty* because the main context has nothing to save.  That is expected.  Change your `object:` to the operation's context (in fact change it to nil) and you will see it fire on the first save and you will have content. Really; try it.

Answer (score 3):

So, I'm guessing you probably want to update the objects in the defaultContext when you save them in the background context. MagicalRecord actually already handles that case for you when you create a new context using the helper method. That is, when you do something like this:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *backgroundOperationContext = 
          [NSManagedObjectContext contextThatNotifiesDefaultContextOnMainThread];
```

The context method has already setup the notifications necessary to tell the default context to merge the changes when it saves in the background. All you need to do is keep your context alive in the background operation and call save when you're ready to persist data.

Behind the scenes, the context method is doing exactly when Marcus is suggesting, and that is, adding a notification to the notification center:

```
[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext]        
                                        selector:... 
                                            name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification 
                                          object:backgroundOperationContext]
```

This isn't exactly the code, but this is pretty much what it does.

Bottom line, forget worrying about observing and merging changes from a background context to the default context yourself, MagicalRecord takes care of it for you.

Comment: +1 The creator of MagicalRecord is certainly most likely to know. :)